# vector<double> utilizando ctypes para DLL em Python

Tags: python, c++, dll, vector

Possuo uma `.dll` que dentro dela tem uma função `BOLHA` que retorna um `double`.

O problema é que `BOLHA` tem um `vector<double>` no argumento.

```
extern "C" minhaDLL_API double BOLHA(vector<double> OI);
```

De fato ela possui um `extern "C"` o que me faz acreditar que na hora de compilar a `.dll` isso virou um ponteiro de `double`. Tentei carregar essa função da `.dll` em Python da seguinte forma:

```
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("_DLL.dll")

func = mydll.BOLHA

func.argtypes = [POINTER(c_double)]
func.restype = c_double

returnarray = (c_double * 2)(0.047948, 0.005994)

func(returnarray)
```

Mas ele me retorna o erro:

> [Error -529697949] Windows Error 0xE06D7363

Comment: Você não pode ter nomes de C++ exportados como nomes de C, até onde sei. E `std::vector<double>` não é um ponteiro, definitivamente. Esse código cheira a comportamento indefinido.

Comment: Ele funciona corretamente e compila bem tambem. So o modo de acessar os argumentos que nao parece ser tao simples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que não há uma maneira direta de resolver isso usando Ctypes, descobri que a melhor forma de resolver esse problema é mudando a .dll

É necessário colocar um ponteiro de double no argumento e o seu tamanho como inteiro e entao no inicio da função pode-se transformar esse ponteiro + tamanho em um vetor e prosseguir normal com a função. Dessa forma, pode-se estabelecer a conexão de forma facil com um tipo C sem perder a utilidade do vetor no código.

fica assim na .dll

```
extern "C" minhaDLL_API double BOLHA(double* OI, int size);
```

e dentro da função pode-se fazer a seguinte associação:

```
vector<double> teste(OI, OI + size);
```

agora o vetor teste pode ser utilizado normalmente.

Em python, fica:

```
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("_DLL.dll")

func = mydll.BOLHA

func.argtypes = [POINTER(c_double), c_int]
func.restype = c_double

returnarray = (c_double * 2)(0.047948, 0.005994)

func(returnarray, 2)
```